# .NET form with Bootstrap 3.3.5

Tags: .net, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms, kentico

I am working on integrating Bootsrap forms into Kentico CMS which is powered by .NET. In doing so I noticed that the "form" tag is being stripped from my form.

I received the following from Kentico Support - I'm afraid that custom form tags are not supported in ASP.NET WebForms. The problem is that in ASP.NET the whole page is wrapped in a form tag (this is the standard .NET behavior not specific to Kentico), and the HTML standard doesn't allow nested form tags.

I have a page template built out with the error handling in HTML, I do not have any .NET programming experience. Can anyone point me to how I can get the Bootstrap forms error handling and submissions working correctly within .NET?

Thank you!

Here is the current formatting:

```
<form action="" method="post"  id="contact_form">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6 zero-margin-bottom">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Company">Company</label>
                <input name="company" type="company" class="form-control" id="exampleInputCompany" placeholder="Company">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
                <input name="first_name" type="firstname" class="form-control" id="exampleInputFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
                <input name="last_name" type="lastname" class="form-control" id="exampleInputLastName" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 zero-margin-bottom">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Phone</label>
                <input name="phone" type="phone" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPhome" placeholder="Phone">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="country">Country</label>
                <select name="country" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select Country</option>
                    <option value="Abu Dhabui">Abu Dhabui</option>
                    <option value="...">Afghanistan</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 zero-margin-bottom">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
                <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit btn-danger">Send Request</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Kentico, but their website claims developers can use the standard .Net controls. I would try that route. Are you using Visual Studio to create the piece you're working on?

Comment: I am not. I am taking the styled Bootstrap HTML developed and integrating it into templates within Kentico. Another part is that I will need to post the form to our CRM by having the code below.

<form id="default-behavior" action="" class="pure-form" id="" method="GET">
<input type=hidden name="Customer" value="...">
<input type=hidden name="cke" value="1">
<input type=hidden name="ownerid" value="12">
<input type=hidden name="overwrite" value="1">
<input type=hidden name="DialogID" value="243">
<input type=hidden name="rurl" value="">

Comment: As the email said, if you're using ASP.NET Web Forms, then the entire body of the HTML page is already wrapped in a `<form>` tag. If you add another form inside of your page, then the HTML standard dictates that the inner form gets stripped from the DOM, as it is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap validation does not rely on form tag. It basically adds `.has-error` class to the parent element. Use inspector (F12 in Chrome) to check your markup and male sure `.has-error` class has been added to the parent element.

> Bootstrap includes validation styles for error, warning, and success
>   states on form controls. To use, add .has-warning, .has-error, or
>   .has-success to the parent element. Any .control-label, .form-control,
>   and .help-block within that element will receive the validation
>   styles.

Find more details [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation).

[Here](https://codepen.io/jaycbrf/pen/iBszr) is working example.

Comment: This example was my starting point, the form tag follows the container div though. When I try and change the form tag to a div the validation no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<form>` tag, it's not needed.  If your styling is dependent on that form tag, then add a different class on a div wrapped around all the form elements.  By default, you can't have a `<form>` nested in a `<form>` using asp.net webforms development.  Kentico's portal development model is using that and it will cause issues every time because the `<form>` tag is on the master page template in the file system (which is recommended to NOT modify).

Comment: When I remove the form tag and add the id="contact_form" to the div that wraps around the form fields the Bootstrap error validation no longer works.

Comment: Then you may need to add some additional classes, override some of the css classes or override some of the bootstrap javascript handlers.  Are you getting any JS errors in the console window?

Comment: Not getting any JS errors and no success with validation yet.